# Draw a rectangle with rounded ends in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I want to draw some round-ended rectangles to use as labels, so I thought a filled arc either end would work (silly me :-)

```
\draw [fill](0,0) arc[radius=5pt,start angle= 90,end angle=270];
\draw [fill](0,0) rectangle (40,-20);
\draw [fill](40,0) arc[radius=5pt,start angle=270,end angle=90];
```

But this places the right-hand end-cap *above* the rectangle, and facing the wrong way. I have obviously misunderstood the implications of the direction angles.

How do I draw a filled arc that points right, not left? (that is, D-shaped, the mirror of the first one).

Comment: If you load the `shapes.misc` TiKZ library, you can use the shape `rounded rectangle` which does exactly what I think you want.

Comment: I think you want a start angle of `90` and an end angle of `-90` (because you want the curve to go in the opposite direction).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If people come to this question via Google (like me) and want to get only a rectangle with rounded corners:

```
\draw[rounded corners] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 1) {};
```

This is an empty rectangle with rounded corners. The rectangle is from `(0, 0)` - the lower left corner - to `(4, 1)` - the upper right corner.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Also works with `\node[rectangle, rounded corners]`

Comment: Worth noting you can use an argument for the radius of the corners:
`\draw[rounded corners=1cm] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 1) {};` (surprisingly, [by default the unit appears to be `pt` rather than `cm`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322041/how-to-set-the-radius-of-rounded-corners-relatively-to-default-unit)).

Comment: I'm using overleaf and when I try this (or any other solutions), I keep getting the error "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/roundedcorners' and I am going to ignore it." Any idea why that is?

Comment: Worth checking whether shapes is in your `\usetikzlibrary` directive, eg
`\usetikzlibrary{svg.path,positioning,shapes,calc,arrows.meta}`

Answer (score 31):

This shows how to adjust the angles in your original commands (I've scaled the rectangle down just so the labels show up better) and then demonstrates the use of `rounded rectangle` from the `shapes.misc` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) arc[radius=5pt,start angle= 90,end angle=270];
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (40pt,-20pt);
    \draw (40pt,0) arc[radius=5pt,start angle=90,end angle=-90];
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) [draw, rounded rectangle] {rounded rectangle};
    \node (2) [below=of 1, draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle west arc=0pt] {rounded rectangle};
    \node (3) [below=of 2, draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle east arc=0pt] {rounded rectangle};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rounded rectangles - multiple ways]

Comment: Thank you...I didn't even check the documentation for that because I thought it was too unlikely a shape to have been considered!

Comment: @PeterFlynn There are some weird and wonderful shapes in the `shapes` library. Who would have thought that there would be specific shapes for `magnetic tape` and `chamfered rectangle` shapes, for example?

Answer (score 29):

Why not using `rounded corners` locally/globally on the path?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  (0,0) {[rounded corners=15pt] --
  ++(2,0)  -- 
  ++(0,1)} --
  ++(-2,0) --
  cycle;
\draw[rounded corners=15pt]
  (4,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gonzalo Mendina What do -- and plus plus do

Comment: @gonzalo Medina please how to write under it ?

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(2.6,2.8)
  % right end round
  \psline(2.2,2.8)(0,2.8)(0,2)(2.2,2)
  \psarc(2.2,2.4){0.4}{270}{90}
  \rput(1.3,2.4){Text~C}
  % left end round
  \psarc(0.4,1.4){0.4}{90}{270}
  \psline(0.4,1)(2.6,1)(2.6,1.8)(0.4,1.8)
  \rput(1.3,1.4){Text~B}
  % both ends round
  \psarc(0.4,0.4){0.4}{90}{270}
  \psline(0.4,0)(2.2,0)
  \psline(0.4,0.8)(2.2,0.8)
  \psarc(2.2,0.4){0.4}{270}{90}
  \rput(1.3,0.4){Text~A}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

```
\draw[rounded corners](0,0)--(5,0)--(5,10)--(0,10)--cycle;
```

Comment: or a bit shorter: `\draw[rounded corners]  (0,0) |- (5,10) |- cycle;` ... , anyway +1