# tikz: Draw rectangle with rounded corners only north/south?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rounded-corners

I'm trying to draw two rectangles (using `\fill` and a cycle) where only the north/south corners are rounded. I want the blue rectangle below to have rounded corners only on the top, and I want the red rectangle on the bottom to have rounded corners only on the bottom.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [blue,rounded corners=10, draw]
  (0,0) --
  ++(5,0) --
  ++(0,5) --
  ++(-5,0) --
  cycle
  {};
\fill [red,rounded corners=10, draw]
  (0,0) --
  ++(5,0) --
  ++(0,-5) --
  ++(-5,0) --
  cycle
  {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Can someone help me with this?

These questions might hint on solutions, but I couldn't get it to work with `\fill` or `\draw`:
[Rounded corners on only one side of a TikZ node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28115/rounded-corners-on-only-one-side-of-a-tikz-node)
[Draw a rectangle with rounded ends in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211342/draw-a-rectangle-with-rounded-ends-in-tikz)
[TikZ rectangular node with different rounded corners](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32867/tikz-rectangular-node-with-different-rounded-corners)

Comment: `tcolorbox` does this out of the box, but perhaps, you want do do other things with your boxes

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211345/586 Also, why not use a `node`?

Comment: Thank you! As a beginner, can I ask: why use a node? I only need the shape, not any text.

Comment: Well, there are pros and cons to both I suppose. With nodes you can give the shapes names, which give access to the anchors, that can be used for e.g. relative positioning, and it lets you use the `fit` library (see manual). You may not need any of that for your use, of course.

Comment: Thanks! For the figure I had in mind I only needed the shape. I will look at the manual more closely in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions! I liked the method proposed in the answer [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) linked to the most, so I'm answering here myself.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [blue,draw]
  (0,0) --
  ++(5,0) {[rounded corners=10] --
  ++(0,5) --
  ++(-5,0)} --
  cycle
  {};
\fill [red,draw]
  (0,0) --
  ++(5,0) {[rounded corners=10] --
  ++(0,-5) --
  ++(-5,0)} --
  cycle
  {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I like this one. The other answers seem to provide alternatives ways of achieving the same effect without directly answering the question from the title. This answer generalizes better to other contexts in which a similar effect is wanted, but the tricks from the other answers cannot be applied.

Answer (score 7):

One box and a `path picture`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{bicolor/.style args={#1 and #2}{
  path picture={
    \tikzset{rounded corners=0}
    \fill [#1] (path picture bounding box.west)
      rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
    \fill [#2] (path picture bounding box.west)
      rectangle (path picture bounding box.south east);
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [bicolor={blue and red}, rounded corners=2ex] 
  (0,0) rectangle (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}



\begin{document}




\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\begingroup % for `\offinterlineskip` 
\offinterlineskip
\tcbset{arc=0.5cm,auto outer arc}
\begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter,after=\par\nointerlineskip,sharp corners=south,height=4cm,colback=blue,boxrule=0pt,width=4cm]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter,after=\par\nointerlineskip,sharp corners=north,height=4cm,colback=red,boxrule=0pt,width=4cm]
\end{tcolorbox}
\endgroup
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the `bicolor` option, this could be done even with one box alone

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[clip,rounded corners=10](0,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\fill [blue]
  (0,0) --
  ++(5,0) --
  ++(0,5) --
  ++(-5,0) --
  cycle
  {};
\fill [red]
  (0,0) --
  ++(5,0) --
  ++(0,-5) --
  ++(-5,0) --
  cycle
  {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution. Same rectangle is drawn twice, but the second one filled with another color and clipped to just show half of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [blue,rounded corners=10, draw]
  (0,0) rectangle (5,10);
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\fill [red,rounded corners=10, draw]
  (0,0) rectangle (5,10);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]