# How to set the radius of rounded corners relatively to default unit

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, lengths, units

*Background:* When I draw a `tikzpicture`, I use only the default units (i.e. I do not specify any unit, as in `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);`).

*Issue:* When no unit is given in the `[rounded corners = <value>]` option, `TikZ` seems to assume the given length is expressed in `pt`, i.e. not in the same unit than the default one. This phenomenon is highlighted in the example below. (This might be due to the fact that `[rounded corners]` = `[rounded corners = 4pt]`?)

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
        \draw [help lines, black!10] (-.5,-.5) grid (7.5,3.5);

        \draw [rounded corners=1] (0,0) rectangle ++(3,3) node [midway] {\footnotesize\texttt{rounded corners=1}};

        \draw [rounded corners=1cm] (4,0) rectangle ++(3,3) node [midway] {\footnotesize\texttt{rounded corners=1cm}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Question:** I would like to specify the radius of rounded corners as a multiple of the default unit (without assuming `1 default unit = 1cm`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: The same issue occurs when you specify `minimum height = 15` in `\node [draw, single arrow] at (0,0) {};` (`\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}` is needed for this).

Comment: If you want consistency, add cm to everything.

Comment: well, that's not very convenient... I'd be glad if there is a more flexible approach!

Comment: The conversion to 1pt is done by latex, usually with an error message.  The conversion to 1cm is done by the tikz path parser,

Comment: Tikz uses its own parser.  From \path to ; everything is being processed by tikz so normal latex rules do not apply.  The options however are process by pgfkeys, although it appears the error message !  Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) is suppressed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, you can always save the default unit in a macro and write `rounded corners=<number>\macroname`. Or you could use a wrapper style definition which automates this. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  ebo unit/.store in=\ebounit,
  ebo corners/.style={rounded corners=#1\ebounit},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, ebo unit=cm]
  \draw [help lines, black!10] (-.5,-.5) grid (7.5,3.5);
  \draw [ebo corners=1] (0,0) rectangle ++(3,3) node [midway] {\footnotesize\texttt{rounded corners=1}};
  \draw [rounded corners=1cm] (4,0) rectangle ++(3,3) node [midway] {\footnotesize\texttt{rounded corners=1cm}};
  \begin{scope}[ebo unit=mm,blue]
    \draw [ebo corners=5] (0,0) ++(.25,.25) rectangle ++(3,3) node [midway] {\footnotesize\texttt{rounded corners=5}};
    \draw [rounded corners=5mm] (4,0) ++(.25,.25) rectangle ++(3,3) node [midway] {\footnotesize\texttt{rounded corners=5mm}};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[ebo unit=ex,green]
    \draw [ebo corners=8] (0,0) ++(-.25,-.25) rectangle ++(3,3) node [midway] {\footnotesize\texttt{rounded corners=8}};
    \draw [rounded corners=8ex] (4,0) ++(-.25,-.25) rectangle ++(3,3) node [midway] {\footnotesize\texttt{rounded corners=8ex}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ebo corners and rounded corners]