# Draw basic diagrams with explanation

Tags: tikz-styles

I am new in world of latex so I was wondering if someone could help me out. I am trying to draw symbols with tikz package but I am not able to find a way how to explain this symbol in front of it like in this picture. Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211342/draw-a-rectangle-with-rounded-ends-in-tikz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87956/1952) symbols and place them inside a `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols,shapes.misc}

\tikzset{
    start-end/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
    },
    input/.style={ % requires library shapes.geometric
        draw,
        trapezium,
        trapezium left angle=60,
        trapezium right angle=120,
    },
    operation/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle
    },
    loop/.style={ % requires library shapes.misc
        draw,
        chamfered rectangle,
        chamfered rectangle xsep=2cm
    },
    decision/.style={ % requires library shapes.geometric
        draw,
        diamond,
        aspect=#1
    },
    decision/.default=1,
    print/.style={ % requires library shapes.symbols
        draw,
        tape,
        tape bend top=none
    },
    connection/.style={
        draw,
        circle,
        radius=5pt,
    },
    process rectangle outer width/.initial=0.15cm,
    predefined process/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        append after command={
        \pgfextra{
          \draw
          ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)-(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$)--
          ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/process rectangle outer width},0.5\pgflinewidth)$)--
          ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/process rectangle outer width},+0.5\pgflinewidth)$)--
          ($(\tikzlastnode.south west)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$);
          \draw
          ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)-(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$)--
          ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/process rectangle outer width},-0.5\pgflinewidth)$)--
          ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/process rectangle outer width},0.5\pgflinewidth)$)--
          ($(\tikzlastnode.south east)+(0,0.5\pgflinewidth)$);
        }  
        },
        text width=#1,
        align=center
    },
    predefined process/.default=1.75cm,
    man op/.style={ % requires library shapes.geometric
        draw,
        trapezium,
        shape border rotate=180,
        text width=2cm,
        align=center,
    },
    extract/.style={
        draw,
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
        shape border rotate=90
    },
    merge/.style={
        draw,
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
        shape border rotate=-90
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cm{6cm}}
\toprule
Simbolo & Significato \\
\midrule
\tikz
\node[start-end] (start) {Start/End};
&
Inizio/Fine \\

\tikz \node[input](inp){Input}; & \dots \\ 

\tikz \node[operation] (op) {Operation}; & Attività operativa \newline Sub-attività informatizzata \newline Macrofase per la quale \dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]