# TikZ: rounded rectangle specifying dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am studying [Draw a rectangle with rounded ends in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211342/draw-a-rectangle-with-rounded-ends-in-tikz) but it appears that the dimensions of the rectangle are dependent on the text in the node.

How can I draw a rounded rectangle specifying dimensions:

1. in a node

   How to change `\node (1) [draw, rounded rectangle] {some text};`?
2. not in a node

   How to change `\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);`

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: `\draw[rounded corners](0,0)rectangle(4,4)` work !

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13588/ for changing size of nodes.

Comment: @Viesturs if the answer meets your requirement you may like to accept and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should point you in the correct direction -- you can experiment with the style

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
    rect/.style={
        font=\small,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!25,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        minimum width=1em, 
        text width=2em,
        draw=blue!75,
        very thick,
        align=center,
        }
    }
\tikz\node[draw, rect]at (0,0)(){A};
\tikz\draw[rect] (3,0) rectangle(4,4);
\end{document}
```

Comment: How could I provide color as an argument to this `tikzset`?

Comment: simply edit `top color=#1` and `bottom color=#2` and `draw=#3` then in the code in the square brackets add colors with comma separated `[draw, rect, red, blue]` etc

Comment: ... or in the code of the `rect` key,  you can replace `blue` by `#1` then use, `rect=blue`, `rect=red` or `rect=orange`.